# Registration or Licensing for an Adobe Air software

Tags: apache-flex, air, licensing

I am making a Adobe Air software which needs to work on Windows, Mac and Linux. One of the issues that has confused me is the registration/licensing process.

Basically, I want users to try out the full version of software for a month and then buy if they find it useful. What I am not able to figure out is how the licensing would work on all these platforms.

- There are no registries in Mac and Linux where I can store the trial information.
- If I somehow maintain things locally in a db, post trial, if the user simply uninstalls and re-installs the software, the trial would start again for 30 days.
- Don't want to store things in filesystem as that's not even close to actual authentication.
- Doing an online activation of the software is a little resource consuming and has network dependency, so that option is also out of scope.

What way should I choose? what other options do I have? Does adobe provide any support for this... any 3rd party libraries that I can use for free?

Comment: Adobe is not continuing to support Adobe AIR on Linux, so you'll have to be fine with an older version of AIR.  I'm not sure when that changed, but I thought it was before AIR 3.  That said, this is not a programming question so I voted to close.  StackOverflow is not a recommendation engine.  It seems to me that if you aren't willing to store information local, and are not willing to store information remotely you're out of options.  But, Sharify and NitroLM are two solutions.  There is a third one out there that escapes me.

Answer (score 1):

I use LimeLM (https://wyday.com/limelm) to do licensing for my Adobe Air app (Windows and Mac, no linux). Like you I have a 30 day trial, LimeLM has a trial feature which is tied to the hardware, so uninstalling/reinstalling won't give users another free trial.

LimeLM requires network activation BUT you can allow for grace periods, so someone must connect to the network, say, once in 30 days of use to activate.

I agree with the above post that EncryptedLocalStore is a good idea as well.

Unfortunately the licensing options for Adobe AIR is limited. LimeLM is functional and cheap (they don't take a cut of purchase price). I looked at NitroLM, which is very expensive (I think they take 30% of purchase price) and very complicated - I could never make sense of it. Zaqon also is out there. I didn't like the way their licensing interface looked to our users. LimeLM was the most flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [EncryptedLocalStore](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/EncryptedLocalStore.html)? Data stored in ELS remains even after app uninstallation.

Comment: From the page you linked: "Do not use the ELS to store applications secrets such as DRM keys or licensing tokens"